# web host claims angular is not supported?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, angularjs, webserver, web-hosting

I just published my asp.net project to winhost.com  everything works except the angular. i assumed it was a linking problem or incorrect path. the jquery is working just fine. the error i get when try to load a page is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=TexasIceApp&p1=Err…js.org%2F1.2.15%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dn%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(...<omitted>...0) angular?v=6jQV6BPRZJTlcNP9nKz6ZUgFHWMVvjTNRZaZrqGn2mI1:1
```

when i run it on my localhost everything works just fine. when i emailed there support staff this was there response:
Hello,

I'm sorry but we don't support AngularJS in our hosting environment.

Please let me know if you have any further questions,

Moises
WinHost Support Department

how could it not be supported? isnt it javascript?? has anyone else had this problem?

APP.js

'use strict';
var app = angular.module('TexasIceApp', [
    'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.bootstrap',
   'ngEkathuwa'
])

BundleConfig

```
 public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"

                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-cookies.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js",
                    "~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                    "~/MyScripts/app.js",

                    "~/MyScripts/AjaxPostController.js",
                    "~/MyScripts/AjaxItemController.js",
                    "~/MyScripts/AjaxGalleryController.js",

                    "~/MyScripts/MainController.js",
                    "~/MyScripts/ekathuwa.js"));
        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js",
                  "~/Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js",
                  "~/Scripts/FileUpload/jqueryui/jquery.ui-widget.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js",
                  "~/MyScripts/MyJquery.js",
                  "~/MyScripts/lightbox.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css",
                  "~/Content/FileUpload/css/jqueryui/jquery.fileupload-ui.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: I am guessing, they mean to say that any issues with AngularJS are not taken care of and you need to debug the issue on your own and not that their hosting does not allow AngularJS

Comment: Can you paste the full error? Based on the initial text, it seems like you may not have defined the dependencies properly. Paste the angular.module() code here.

Comment: the error in my chrome console?  might be easier if you take a look. http://www.rudymsanchez.com/myapp

Comment: You are making use of the `ngResource` and `ngCookies` and `ngRoute` angular modules but I did not see them defined anywhere - are you including them in your application too? At least, in the minified version, I could not locate them.

Comment: i just updated my post, i put some code in there. thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help further. I am not familiar with asp.net. The issue, based on the error raised in console is that when AngularJS instantiates, it can't find dependent modules - particularly the AngularJS ones (ngResource, ngRoute, ngCookies).

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the generated code for Angular I *think* the problem may be that you have the  `ngEkathuwa` defined last in the Angular bundle (the ekathuwa.js file).  Put the ekathuwa.js file before app.js in the Bundle definition and if my hunch is correct, that will solve your problem.

Comment: just got a email back from them...You're running into the error because the path is wrong:

E:\web\rudymsan\Images\IceCarvings\TexasIceCarvingBlock.jpg

Because you published your application to the /myapp directory, the path should be:

E:\web\rudymsan\myapp\Images\IceCarvings\TexasIceCarvingBlock.jpg

This might be the same reason your AngularJS is not working correctly.

Please let me know if you have any further questions,

Rei T.
WinHost Support Department     how would i change the path of the angular scripts?